# chm file "This page can't be displayed." **It is different issue from the other questions related to same error message**

Tags: chm

CHM file opening with message "This page can't be displayed" when press F1.

Using Windows Server 2008 R2 and 2012 R2. Getting error in both the version servers.

**The file is at local server path and it is not blocked.**

```
This page can't be displayed Make sure the web address 
//ieframe.dll/dnserrordiagoff.htm# is correct.  
Look for the page with your search engine.  
Refresh the page in a few minutes.
```

When try to open the page with below query working fine

```
hh.exe ms-its:C:\XXXX\common.chm::/XXXX/Open_Tab_-_XXXX_Window.htm#Retrieve
```

Note: Few servers it is working properly but majority of the servers having aforementioned issue. Have checked the MS KB patches and content b/w the server where working fine and having issue.

Any Suggestion please.

**Note: It is different issue from the other questions related to same error message**

Have verified the answers of all other questions but the suggestion not resolved my issue.

Comment: Hint to others that come here for similar problems: If the specified htm file is missing/mis-spelled also the same error message is shown, so if your chm is on local disc and doesn't have the unsafe flag set you could check whether the page actually exist (as Venkatesh R showed above with the call to hh.exe)

Answer (score 0):

In a thread several months old, the problem is also described. Please see [Applying recent Windows updates appears to prevent HTML help files from displaying correctly when accessed remotely (UNC & network drive)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/f8875952-25ac-4c27-b72b-a55f960e5e64/applying-recent-windows-updates-appears-to-prevent-html-help-files-from-displaying-correctly-when?forum=winservergen).

Reading down to Thursday, October 4, 2018 9:30 AM you'll find:

Problem was solved with https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4458469 for W10
and with 2018-09 Preview of Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows Server 2008 R2 for x64-based Systems (KB4457139)"

> Addresses an issue that prevents the Microsoft Help Viewer from rendering HTML content inside a Windows Help .chm file when the .chm file is stored on a network location.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the info. I have tried to install the KB4458469 and KB4457139 but it is unsuccessfull. getting "the update is not applicable to your computer" message while installing the file.

Comment: pretty old this topic but I get the same error trying to install KB4458469 under Win10. I receive the same error code trying to open CHM files

Answer (score 0):

The reason I found for this error was the name of the folder that contained the CHM file. To distinguish it from an earlier version of the program in another language, I included "C#" in the folder name. As it turns out, this caused many features to go crazy. So I removed the "C#" from the folder name and the problem went away.